# What is this sound effect? (Lady Gaga's Monster)

Tags: voice

"But I can't stop staring in those evil eyes
 evil eyes
 **evilllllvvveeeeellllllll**"

How do you make a sound (in bold above) like that? Is there a name for it?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, the pitch of the sound is being *progressively* reduced. It used to be that the most straightforward way to do this (e.g. with analogue equipment like tape, or simple computer programs) was to *slow down* the audio, as that naturally reduces the pitch of the sound too. With modern digital technology, though, it's possible to manipulate pitch and speed independently. I must admit that I can't tell from the Gaga track if it's slowing down a bit or not...

If you have Audacity, you can experiment with both pitch and speed reduction using the *Effect > Sliding Time Scale/Pitch Shift* menu.

This kind of effect, when done in such a way as to sound like the abrupt sound of a tape machine being stopped with the play head still engaged, is often called a *tape stop* effect. There is a large numbers of tutorials on YouTube of how to do this with various programs, but actually, the particular example you've found doesn't stop quite as abruptly as a typical 'tape stop'.